# SPI drought index

Tags: r, plot

I have the following data:

> pcp # precipitation monthly data from 2001-01,2020-12

I have used the following to compute the SPI drought index

```
library(SPEI)

spi1 <- spi(pcp,1,kernel = list(type = "rectangular", shift = 0),distribution = "Gamma", fit = "ub-pwm", na.rm = FALSE,ref.start=NULL, ref.end=NULL, x=FALSE, params=NULL)
```

First question:
 when I plot(spi1) I get SPEI on the Y axis which I don't want , what I want is SPI,
second:
how to plot each month separately for example when you call spi1 it will give you the index value for each month, and I want to plot it for each month

Comment: It's usually a sign you need to do some reading of manuals when 3 of the last 3 questions are yours.

Comment: I have done so, but the data type is new to me and the function spi is new to me I have read how to handle it using R but I have some few questions to ask like why it is always SPEI on the Y axis not SPI

Comment: @TylerRinker is right because this is very basic R and at least provide a reproductible example. They are millions of functions in R scattered around 5000 packages, so please tell us which package did you use to compute the spi. With a full reproductible example may be you'll get some help.

Comment: Is not the right attitude bro. No one is paid here to answer to your questions and you should seriously read more about the packages you use and more generally about R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first answer, you can rewrite the function `plot.spei`

```
plot.spei <- 
function (x, ...) 
{
    ## label <- ifelse(as.character(x$call)[1] == "spei", "SPEI", 
    ##     "SPI")

    ser <- ts(as.matrix(x$fitted[-c(1:x$scale), ]), end = end(x$fitted), 
        frequency = frequency(x$fitted))
    ser[is.nan(ser - ser)] <- 0
    se <- ifelse(ser == 0, ser, NA)
    tit <- dimnames(x$coefficients)[2][[1]]
    if (start(ser)[2] == 1) {
        ns <- c(start(ser)[1] - 1, 12)
    }
    else {
        ns <- c(start(ser)[1], start(ser)[2] - 1)
    }
    if (end(ser)[2] == 12) {
        ne <- c(end(ser)[1] + 1, 1)
    }
    else {
        ne <- c(end(ser)[1], end(ser)[2] + 1)
    }
    n <- ncol(ser)
    if (is.null(n)) 
        n <- 1
    par(mar = c(4, 4, 2, 1) + 0.1)
    if (n > 1 & n < 5) 
        par(mfrow = c(n, 1))
    if (n > 1 & n >= 5) 
        par(mfrow = c({
            n + 1
        }%/%2, 2))
    for (i in 1:n) {
        datt <- ts(c(0, ser[, i], 0), frequency = frequency(ser), 
            start = ns, end = ne)
        datt.pos <- ifelse(datt > 0, datt, 0)
        datt.neg <- ifelse(datt <= 0, datt, 0)
        plot(datt, type = "n", xlab = "", main = tit[i], ...)
        if (!is.null(x$ref.period)) {
            k <- ts(5, start = x$ref.period[1, ], end = x$ref.period[2, 
                ], frequency = 12)
            k[1] <- k[length(k)] <- -5
            polygon(k, col = "light grey", border = NA, density = 20)
            abline(v = x$ref.period[1, 1] + (x$ref.period[1, 
                2] - 1)/12, col = "grey")
            abline(v = x$ref.period[2, 1] + (x$ref.period[2, 
                2] - 1)/12, col = "grey")
        }
        grid(col = "black")
        polygon(datt.pos, col = "blue", border = NA)
        polygon(datt.neg, col = "red", border = NA)
        lines(datt, col = "dark grey")
        abline(h = 0)
        points(se, pch = 21, col = "white", bg = "black")
    }
}
```

And then use the `ylab` parameters

```
plot(spi1, ylab = "SPI")
```

If you want to plot it separately, you can extract the fitted value of class `ts` and apply basic plotting for time series object in R.

```
par(mfrow = c(3, 4))
listofmonths <- split(fitted(spi1), cycle(fitted(spi1)))
names(listofmonths) <- month.abb

require(plyr)
l_ply(seq_along(listofmonths), function(x) {
       plot(x = seq_along(listofmonths[[x]]), y = listofmonths[[x]],
            type = "l", xlab = "", ylab = "SPI")
       title(names(listofmonths)[x])
   })
```

You can also try these types of plot

```
monthplot(fitted(spi1), labels = month.abb, cex.axis = 0.8)
boxplot(fitted(spi1) ~ cycle(fitted(spi1)), names = month.abb, cex.axis = 0.8)
```

Comment: I have a question since I'm new to programming I need an advice to develop my programming ability

Comment: There's no secret, you have to read a lot of documentation and try hard to finish project with R. Participating here by answering to questions helps too. R is so powerful that you'll have fun going through all of this.

Comment: Can I ask you a question which code did you change in plot.spei? if you don't mind

Comment: I commented one part of the code, at the begin which start with `##label....` and I added ellipsis `...` to `plot` call at the end and removed `ylab = label`.